# sending SMS per app in android - is there any technical difference to sending manually?

Tags: android, sms

I have an app which sends normal text SMS to a device to turn it on or off.

I just use the normal sms method:

```
SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
sms.sendTextMessage(phoneNumber, null, message, sentPI, deliveredPI);
```

In hundred of cases the SMS sent by the App do exactly the same as sending SMS manually. However, I have one user who claims, that sending SMS manually has a different effect than sending the SMS from within the app. In fact he claims that with the App the device does not function while sending SMS manually works. What is even stranger is the fact, that the device responds in both cases with a confirmation SMS.

Is that technically possible? Are there any special technical settings that one could change in Android phones when sending SMS? I really can't imagine that there can even be a difference.

many thanks for all your hints

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're trying to solve this other way around.
If device sends a confirmation SMS but doesn't function as expected, you probably want the logs from the device.

The actual answer: No. SMS application is using the same API.